# Where can I find early posts about Bitcoin where trolls are arguing over distribution?

Tags: wealth-distribution

I'm doing research on Bitcoin and looking for early posts about Bitcoin regarding unfair distribution. I'm sure there were posts arguing the fact that most of the Bitcoins were in the hands of only a handful of early adopters. And how many?

Answer (score 2):

Try searching BitCoinTalk.org, it has messages from Satoshi going back to late 2009, so I would assume if these messages existed they would be there.

Answer (score 1):

[Here's a huge infographic concerning distribution.](http://www.cryptocoinsnews.com/news/owns-bitcoins-infographic-wealth-distribution/2014/03/21) You may also check out the [distribution of companies in the globe](http://www.washingtonpost.com/blogs/the-switch/wp/2014/03/03/forget-the-1-percent-in-the-bitcoin-world-half-the-wealth-belongs-to-the-0-1-percent/).

For early posts, only bitcointalk (and, after a while, reddit) can be of help.  There was a huge debate during the Occupy movement, as many individuals there thought the distribution wasn't "fair".